# 401 unauthorized error while trying to access user context in MS teams from my bot

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

I have deployed a bot using bot framework composer and deployed it on MS teams. Now that I want to incorporate personalized messages to greet the user, I'm trying to follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json#get-single-member-details

below is the 401 exception I'm getting.

```
    {
      "type": "message",
      "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:49558",
      "channelId": "emulator",
      "from": {
      "id": "<>id",
      "name": "Bot",
      "role": "bot"
    },
   "conversation": {
      "id": "<id>"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": "<id>",
      "role": "user"
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "text": "{\r\n  \"statusCode\": 401,\r\n  \"reasonPhrase\": \"Unauthorized\",\r\n  \"headers\": {\r\n    
    \"Server\": \"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\",\r\n    \"Date\": \"Fri, 05 Mar 2021 10:29:31 GMT\"\r\n  },\r\n  
    \"content\": {\r\n    \"message\": \"Authorization has been denied for this request.\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
    "speak": "{\r\n  \"statusCode\": 401,\r\n  \"reasonPhrase\": \"Unauthorized\",\r\n  \"headers\": 
    {\r\n    \"Server\": \"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\",\r\n    \"Date\": \"Fri, 05 Mar 2021 10:29:31 
      GMT\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"content\": {\r\n    \"message\": \"Authorization has been denied for this 
      request.\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
    "attachments": [],
    "entities": [],
    "replyToId": "<id>",
    "id": "<id>",
    "localTimestamp": "2021-03-05T15:59:32+05:30",
    "timestamp": "2021-03-05T10:29:32.254Z"
    }
```

Any advice will be greatly helpful.

Comment: It looks like you're calling to serviceUrl of http://localhost:49558, is that correct? ServiceUrl should be somthing like "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea" or similar (it's different for different user/tenant regions). ChannelId should also probably be something other than "emulator"

Comment: Nope, I have been calling smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/<convID>/members/<memberID>
Also, providing valid values for conversation and member ID. Am I missing any Auth token in the req? I'm not passing any right now?

Comment: Ah ok, wanted to confirm. In that case, for an authentication issue, make sure the bot app id and app password ("client secret") are set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I was finally able to get the right auth code. Now the endpoint is throwing 502 Bad Gateway error. I'm calling the smba.trafficmanager.net/amer. Any thoughts?

Comment: perhaps explain your scenario better... are you trying to send a "welcome" message when they first join, or a "proactive" message some time in the future?

Comment: I'm trying to wish user by their name. For example, "Welcome, Hilton" as a greeting message. To get the user full name, I'm trying to make the call to smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/<convID>/members/<memberID> which is supposed to return me the user profile information like fullname and email id etc., Now this API returns 502 error with below in response body.
{
"error": {
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "message": "Service Error."
    }
}

Comment: ok I think I got it - posted a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of the user, there is an API as part of the Bot Framework specifically for operations like this in Teams. See [Get single member details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details). This will show how to get the user's details, so as to send them a personalized welcome message.

Comment: Yes, this is the same URL I was calling. Also, mentioned the same in one of my comments above. The same API call is returning me 502 error

Comment: Yes under the covers it makes the same call, but what happens if you use the SDK instead?

Comment: Now that the bot I created is on the composer, can I get its code and extend it? Any documentation in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Composer I'm afraid, I mostly write bots directly (C#/Node). A Skill might help though (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-connect-to-a-skill)

Comment: @user1472423 502 Bad Gateway is because the web app was not running. Please check if you specify the correct message endpoint for the bot.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mamatha-MSFT. I was using this endpoint smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/<convID>/members/<memberID> as I found 'smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/' as the base URL for some calls in my app insights.Am I calling the wrong one?

Comment: @user1472423 Please check if you specify the correct MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftApp Password for your bot on Application Settings and check if you specify the [correct message endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#configuration) for the bot on the Settings.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT, I developed the bot on the composer and deployed it on a web app bot. I made sure the App Id and password are configured correctly in my web app bot but what do you mean by correct message endpoint? Under the configuration section of web app bot, the message endpoint will be auto populated right? Something like this - https://<my bot name>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages.

Comment: @user1472423 the service URL should be https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis followed by /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members/{userId}. Could you please try and let me know if you still persist the issue.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting now when I try the (smba.trafficmanager.net/apis) URL you mentioned above.

"error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "API isn't enabled for the bot"
    }
Any idea about this error?

Comment: Every API request that you issue must include an Authorization header that specifies an access token to authenticate your bot. Please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#base-uri). 

Please look at this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) for user context. It may helps you.

Comment: Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.